# How to sign_in for Devise to Test Controller with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, minitest

I'm newbie to Rails Testing.

After following some tutorial online, I could able to setup and run testing for Model.

But when trying to test for Controller, Testing was failed as it is redirected to login page.

I've tried every instruction I can find on web to sign in for devise and still couldn't able to sign in and move forward.

Appreciate if someone could help and give me a direction to move forward.

```
AwardedBidsControllerTest
  test_should_get_index                                           FAIL (0.45s)
MiniTest::Assertion:         Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <302>
```

Below is my setup

test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!(
  Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new,
  ENV,
  Minitest.backtrace_filter
)

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

test/controllers/awarded_bids_controller_test.rb

```
require "test_helper"

class AwardedBidsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    user = create(:user)
    sign_in user
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

app/controllers/awarded_bids_controller.rb

```
class AwardedBidsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @awarded_bids = AwardedBid.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @awarded_bids }
    end
  end
end
```

test/factories/users.rb

```
#using :login instead of :email.

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.login "user"
    u.name "Normal"
    u.surname "User"
    u.password "Abc2011"
  end
end
```

Below is the version info., 
JRuby 1.7.21(Ruby 1.9.3)
Rails 3.2.22
Devise 3.0.4
Minitest 4.7.5

Comment: Where did you get `create(:user)` from? That's not a method in [ActionController::TestCase](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html). Try creating the model using standard Rails fixtures `users(:one)`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

Answer (score 23):

From [integration_helpers.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/test/integration_helpers.rb), for example:

```
class PostsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  test 'authenticated users can see posts' do
    sign_in users(:bob)

    get '/posts'
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you do the `sign_in` inside the `setup` method to avoid duplication across the various tests?

Answer (score 2):

In your `test_helper.rb` file's `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class, add a new method `log_in_as` like this:

```
require "test_helper"
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!(
    Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new,
    ENV,
    Minitest.backtrace_filter
)

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private

  # Returns true inside an integration test.
  def integration_test?
    defined?(post_via_redirect)
  end
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

Then, use this `log_in_as` method instead of `sign_in` in your test:

```
require "test_helper"

class AwardedBidsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    user = create(:user)
    log_in_as user
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried and it still not work for me. Is the sample above working for you with devise authentication? Thanks.

Comment: yes, it works in one of my projects. Whats the problem now? same message?

Comment: Yes. Still same message.

Comment: do you have your code on github? can I check the code? that way, it would be easier to figure out the problem and solve it quickly.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have on github.

Comment: can you try: `get :index, id: user`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87708/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-thetnaung).

Comment: Hi Raki
i managed to setup repo on github
it's on github.com/thetnaung/minitest_with_devise
you can seed db for testing in dev mode
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi, @Thetnaung, i cloned your repo. Unfortunately, its now working in my computer. It has a lot of gem depency conflicts and I can't even run the tests. sorry :(